# WMIC set "User cannot change password" error : Description = Generic failure

Tags: wmic

when attempting to set password changeable for user then I got the following the error message.

```
NET USER username "XXXXXXX" /ADD
NET LOCALGROUP "administrators" "username" /add
wmic useraccount WHERE Name='username' set PasswordExpires=false

C:\Windows\system32>wmic useraccount WHERE Name='username' set PasswordChangeable=false
Updating property(s) of '\\hostname\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain="hostname",Name="username"'
ERROR:
Description = Generic failure
```

Comment: Your new user doesn't have a password, so option `PasswordExpires` is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking your WMI logs for more detailed error messages. By default in `C:\windows\system32\wbem\logs\wbemess.log` and/or through the eventlog: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wmisdk/tracing-wmi-activity.

I would suspect that wmi couldn't find a user with `Name='username'`, but still tried to update the property and died (or Theo's comment about the user having no password). There are other stranger reasons too like timeout issues or running out of memory etc, but those should show in the logs.

---

I recommend using the Powershell cmdlets instead of direct WMI, but it's personal preference:

```
New-LocalUser -Name 'username' -Password 'password' -PasswordNeverExpires -UserMayNotChangePassword
Add-LocalGroupMember -Group Administrators -Member (Get-LocalUser 'username')
```